# How to select Multiple values from picklist dropdown?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Hi friends I have one visualforce page in that i have i am converting all name in to picklist,but I can not select more than one value without using control key.
How to select more than one value from picklist without using control key.
Hoe to send those values into apex class to fetch details.

Comment: Are you using multi select picklist?

Comment: No @SantanuBoral but i am converting textfield into picklist

Comment: How are you converting the textfield into picklist?

Comment: @shalini usind select option i am convering,,,

Comment: I see 2 different questions here. 1.How to convert text into picklist 2. How to select multipe values from a picklist without using control. The answer to first question is to populate a picklist in the controller which you can then display on vf page. I have a question back to you for the 2nd question of yours. Why dont you want to select using control key? That is what we commonly use to select more than one value(in .xls) using any tool.

Comment: @shalini I want to select picklist values from mouse only..

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (salesforce style) [Multi-Select Picklist](https://github.com/metadaddy/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist)

Alternatively, build something on your own using JS+CSS...

Comment: No Borris I dont want standard multi pick list?

Comment: Then you have to build a custom one - http://loudev.com/

Comment: I tried @Boris but i am not able yto send all selected values to the apex class.